# C# How would I convert grade percentages to letter grades?

Tags: c#

Noob here. I have written a program that allows a user to enter how many grades they would like to input into an array, and then lets them enter the grades for the number of indexes they chose. I am trying to output the total percentage grade based on the inputted grades, and also output the actual letter grade, but I am having trouble figuring out what I would code to convert to letter grades. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int ARRAYLENGTH = 0;
        int i = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("How many scores would you like to enter? ");
        ARRAYLENGTH = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        string[] test = new string[ARRAYLENGTH];

        for (i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)

        {
            Console.Write("Enter your test score " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            test[i] =
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        for (i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum +
            Convert.ToDouble(test[i].Trim());
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nThis is your average = " + (sum / test.Length));
        Console.WriteLine("\nYour grade is: ");//Not sure how this would work
        Console.Write("\nPress the [Enter] key to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, you're better of doing some more assignment (rather than calculating the grade in the print statement) so I've included that below. Once you have the percentage in a var you just use an if/else or a switch to derive the letter grade.

```
double gradePer = sum / test.Length
string gradeLetter = "F";

if (gradePer >= 60 && gradePer < 70) {
     gradeLetter = "D";
} else if (gradePer >= 70 && gradePer < 80) {
     gradeLetter = "C";
} // you fill in the rest

Console.WriteLine("\nThis is your average = " + gradePer);
Console.WriteLine("\nYour grade is: " + gradeLetter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to get your letter grade from the average you computed:

```
static char GetLetterGrade(double score)
{
    if (score >= 90.0)
    {
        return 'A';
    }

    if (score >= 80.0)
    {
        return 'B';
    }

    if (score >= 70.0)
    {
        return 'C';
    }

    if (score >= 60.0)
    {
        return 'D';
    }

    return 'F';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a switch, specificing a range of values for each letter

Answer (score -1):

In the simplest possible way... I would create a dictionary:

```
Key - Value
10 - A
9 - A
8 - B
7 - C
6 - D
5 - F
4 - F
3 - F
2 - F
1 - F
0 - F
```

Now that you have this dictionary set up, you can take the grade into your method, divide by 10, take the floor and find the entry associated with that value.

```
public class Grades
{
    Dictionary<int, char> GradeValues { get; set; }

    public Grades()
    {
        GradeValues.Add(10, 'A');
        GradeValues.Add(9, 'A');
        GradeValues.Add(8, 'B');
        ...
        GradeValues.Add(0, 'F');
    } 
    public char GetGrade(int grade)
    {
        char value = GradeValues[int.Floor(grade/10)];
        if (value == null)
            return 'F';
        return value;
    }
}
```

That being said, there are probably better ways to handle this.

Edit: This assumes that you don't have B- or other grades that happen when a grade of 88 is passed into the method.

If statements or cases would work great too, but I prefer this method of development. It is easier to extend when you want to change a grade. You don't have to update the method. You only need to update the dictionary in the constructor.

Edit 2: I have seen that someone downvoted every answer. I upvoted the other answers as they are all valid...

You could just fill out the entire dictionary from 0 to 100 with the grade for that score.